# How to allow permission via GPO to remove bluetooth devices in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, bluetooth

We have 'Standard' users who test Bluetooth devices. This involves pairing them to a Windows 7 machine.

Unfortunately, each device adds a unique entry to the "Devices and Printers" which 'Standard' users cannot remove (remove is greyed out).

How can I give them access via group policy to remove these entries?

Comment: Are the classes added to the driver installation policy settings?

Comment: Yes.  They can install the Devices just fine too.  They just can't remove them.